# page_action click does not work while browser_action click works in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

I want to make a simple browser extension like [Font Face Ninja](https://fontface.ninja) which toggles UI when `page_action` or `browser_action` is clicked.

The following code using `browser_action` works -

## background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  console.log(`clicked browserAction`)
})
```

## manifest.json

```
{
    ...
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icon19.png",
      "38": "icon38.png"
    }
  },
    ...
}
```

While the following code using `page_action` does not work -

## background.js

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  console.log(`clicked pageAction`)
})
```

## manifest.json

```
{
    ...
    "page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icon19.png",
      "38": "icon38.png"
    }
  },
    ...
}
```

According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/page_action),

> Page actions are like browser actions, except that they are associated with particular web pages rather than with the browser as a whole. If an action is only relevant on certain pages, then you should use a page action and display it only on relevant pages. If an action is relevant to all pages or to the browser itself, use a browser action.

Which confirms I want to use `page_action` but its not working.

How do I make it work using `page_action`?

Comment: page_action is disabled by default, you need to enable it on appropriate tabs individually using show() method, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) that contains links to demo extensions. You can also use [declarativeContent API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent).

Comment: I tried to make it work using demo link but it was giving weird errors so I quit it. I'll come back to this again if I need to. Currently, `browser_action` is working so it's good for now 

Comment: okay so made `page_action` work too using `declarativeContent` → https://github.com/deadcoder0904/insert-remove-ui-chrome-extension/tree/page_action

Comment: @wOxxOm The documentation on page_action is really confusing; and does not say anything about `needing to enable it explicitly`. ATST, your comments are always helpful :thumbsup:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Page Action

A way to make `page_action` work can be found on my Github → https://github.com/deadcoder0904/insert-remove-ui-chrome-extension/tree/page_action

### background.js

```js
var hasExecutedOnce = false

function addUI(tabId) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
    from: 'background',
    subject: 'isUIAdded?',
  })
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'www.google.co.in' },
          }),
        ],
        actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()],
      },
    ])
  })
})

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  if (!hasExecutedOnce) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      tab.id,
      {
        file: 'contentScript.js',
      },
      function() {
        addUI(tab.id)
      },
    )
    hasExecutedOnce = true
  }
  addUI(tab.id)
})
```

### contentScript.js

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]

function insertUI() {
  var div = document.createElement('div')
  div.setAttribute('id', 'sample-extension-12345')
  div.innerHTML = `<h1>Sample Extension</h1>`
  body.appendChild(div)
}

function removeUI() {
  document.getElementById('sample-extension-12345').remove()
}

function main() {
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.subject === 'isUIAdded?') {
      const id = document.getElementById('sample-extension-12345')
      if (id === null) insertUI()
      else removeUI()
    }
  })
}

main()
```

## Browser Action

It also has a solution for `browser_action` on the master branch → https://github.com/deadcoder0904/insert-remove-ui-chrome-extension/

### background.js

```js
var hasExecutedOnce = false

function addUI(tabId) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
    from: 'background',
    subject: 'isUIAdded?',
  })
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  if (!hasExecutedOnce) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      tab.id,
      {
        file: 'contentScript.js',
      },
      function() {
        addUI(tab.id)
      },
    )
    hasExecutedOnce = true
  }
  addUI(tab.id)
})
```

### contentScript.js

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]

function insertUI() {
  var div = document.createElement('div')
  div.setAttribute('id', 'sample-extension-12345')
  div.innerHTML = `<h1>Sample Extension</h1>`
  body.appendChild(div)
}

function removeUI() {
  document.getElementById('sample-extension-12345').remove()
}

function main() {
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.subject === 'isUIAdded?') {
      const id = document.getElementById('sample-extension-12345')
      if (id === null) insertUI()
      else removeUI()
    }
  })
}

main()
```

Comment: Save my day, bro! Spent 3 hours tryina figure it out... If only you would insert the code here.

Comment: @avalanche1 just read [contentScript.js](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/insert-remove-ui-chrome-extension/blob/master/contentScript.js) & [background.js](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/insert-remove-ui-chrome-extension/blob/master/background.js) & you're golden :)

Comment: @avalanche1 done. i've put them as h1 & h2. the first one is page_action & 2nd one is browser action but i do think with manifest v3 the API is changing by the end of the year where we will only have 1 of them but for now you're good to go. let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: Now i can SEE. You're an awesome dude-man!